# $x^2 +1$ is reducible over $\Bbb Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

**How is it true that the polynomial $x^2 +1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$?**

Is it because  that 3 is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ and $3^2 +1=10$ which is divisible by 5.

And so as Polynomial $x^2 +1$ having degree 2 has got a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.
$x^2 +1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

***Is this explanation reasonable?***

Comment: Yes, although because your $3$ is an element of ${\mathbb Z}_5$, I would say that $3^2 + 1 = 10 = 0$, considering everything to be elements of ${\mathbb Z}_5$.

Comment: Or directly $\,x^2+1=x^2-4=(x+2)(x-2)\,$.

Comment: You may want to refer to the theorem which says that, for a field $K$ and a polynomial $f\in K[x]$, $f(\alpha)=0\iff (x-\alpha)\mid f$ (as long as $\deg f\ge1$, the degree being specifically $2$ is irrelevant).

Answer (score 6):

You have found one of the roots, by inspection you will notice that $2$ is also a root. You have
$$x^2+1 = (x-2)(x-3)$$
if $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$X^2+1 \equiv X^2-4 \pmod{5}$$

Now use the difference of squares formula.